# An example how I directly connect to Cassandra by CQL (1)

Tags: python, django, cassandra, cql

I need full example that show me how I can Connect to Cassandra by CQL. I am working on a project that should be written in (python) Django and I want to do some thing directly not only using cqlEngine as my Project Driver.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I made python communicate to cassandra.

First, you need to establish a connection, adding:

```
import cql
con= cql.connect(host="127.0.0.1",port=9160,keyspace="testKS")
```

Then generate a cursor for query:

```
cur=con.cursor()
result=cur.execute("select * from TestCF")
```

And I can see the result by:

```
result.fetchone()
```

or

```
result.fetch()
```

This queries nicely and doesn't need extra library, such pycasaa or cqlengine

Comment: If someone getting `cql.apivalues.ProgrammingError: column name '\x00\x00\x00' can't be deserialized as 'org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.CompositeType': global name 'self' is not defined`. Use `cql_version='3.0.0'` as argument to cql.connect, otherwise it assumes CQL2. For more info check [this issue](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-dbapi2/issues/detail?id=30)